# IdentityServer4 with .NET Framework Client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I have been following the official quickstarts from the IdentityServer4 website, and have successfully got an Identity Server working, along with a .NET Core client. Now however I want to add an older .NET Framework server as a client and am unsure how to go about this. I've tried many vague implementations across the web, most of which included using OWin (unsure why this is necessary) with no luck. If anyone has a nice clean solution to this or a link to someone that does that would be very helpful, as I'm sure I am not the only one trying to connect legacy software to IS4.

I'm very new to this so would appreciate answers that give step by step instructions and preferably show code.

Comment: Someone asked a similar question via a IS4 github issue and Brock answered by pointing to the older IS3 client sample code, which apparently still works against IS4.  See:  https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing MVC web application will also be a Client of the IdentityServer4 authority. You could use the Authorization Code Flow, Implicit or Hybrid flow. code flow is more secure in this case.

The examples of how to setup an ASP.NET MVC web application as a Client of an IdentityServer instance can be found on https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients

Comment: I've taken a look at these but they are not as clear or obvious as to how to use as the .NET Core versions. Do you know if there are any tutorials that actually explain what these are doing or at least how to set up the Identity Server end?

Comment: In your case, IdentityServer4 will be the identity server and an MVC app will be client. You would need to set up the MVC client following Katana based docs: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html and use the IdentityServer4 as `Authority`. Lets chat if this is not what you are working for, I have a blog to make it wok for Web API & IdentityServer4 https://nahidfa.com/posts/identityserver4-and-asp-.net-web-api/ I can add another for MVC & IdentityServer4 later today.

Comment: @Josh https://nahidfa.com/posts/identityserver4-and-asp-.net-mvc/

Comment: Thanks so much for that! I've followed your instructions from your blog and run into one little niggle where instead of redirecting on unauthorised it throws an error and displays a 401 error page. how can I make the server redirect on unauthorised?

Comment: Scratch that last - needed to install Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb

Answer (score 3):

As per nahidfa's comments - nahidfa.com/posts/identityserver4-and-asp-.net-mvc solved my problem. It shows step by step how to get this working and he's also included a sample pack in case you still can't figure it out. Big thanks to nahidfa for making that blog post after seeing my question :)